# Java Annotation @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE) - Also covers declaration contexts?

Tags: java, annotations

This compiles perfectly even though the following annotation is not supposed to be used as a declaration annotation.

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;


// Foo annotation
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Foo {}

@Foo
class Person {}


@Foo
interface Emittable() {}
```

In the above example, the `Foo` annotation type is used in the declaration contexts of `Person` and `Emittable` types, even though it is targeted only for type contexts, and the funny thing is that the code compiles just fine and runs perfectly Does it mean that `ElementType.TYPE_USE` also covers the declaration contexts? According to the Java 14 Language Specification, `ElementType.TYPE_USE` does not cover any declaration contexts. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently-accepted answer is incorrect.

The relevant documentation is at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html and says

> The constant `TYPE_USE` corresponds to the 15 type contexts in JLS 4.11, as well as to two declaration contexts: type declarations (including annotation type declarations) and type parameter declarations.

In other words, `TYPE_USE` is a special case.  The rationale for is that when defining a type qualifier, programmers may often want to write it on declarations as well as uses.
This is laid out in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4 which says:

> two of the nine clauses - for class, interface, enum, and annotation type declarations, and for type parameter declarations - mention "... or type contexts" because it may be convenient to apply an annotation whose type is meta-annotated with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)` (thus, applicable in type contexts) to a type declaration.

The currently-accepted answer quotes text that is about a different matter:  how to interpret the annotations in

```
class C {
  @MyDeclAnno @MyTypeAnno Object myField;
}
```

where `MyDeclAnno` is a declaration annotation and `MyTypeAnno` is a type annotation.
The JLS *grammar* parses both annotations on the declaration.  However, the text quoted in the currently-accepted answer notes that `@MyTypeAnno` as is actually applied to the type `Object` whereas `@MyDeclAnno` is actually applied to the declaration of the field `myField`.

Comment: Sorry for the oversight. Yours must be a better, correct answer. The old answer anyway gave me a clue and that's why I accepted it. I must oblige you for the community. @mernst

Comment: Oh! I overlooked the small print! When I was writing my answer, I kind of thought it was a little bit of a stretch too. I knew the spec was referring to variable/field declarations, but I thought I could apply it to class declarations as well... Although that might not be in the spirit of the spec, I don’t _think_ the wording prevents me from applying it that way? :-)

Comment: @mernst Just realized you're one of the creators of the Checker framework. Great work!

Comment: @Sweeper You're wrong in that sense. If you read on the specification you will find the following clause ```... because it may be convenient to apply an annotation whose type is meta-
annotated with @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE) (thus, applicable in type contexts)
to a type declaration.
```

Comment: @mernst I'd like to invite you to another question of mine. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61926215/3858559