# Java - How do I create an annotation type that is only applicable in type contexts? (PURE type annotation)

Tags: java, annotations, typechecking

To create a type annotation that is applicable in type contexts, there is no way other than meta-annotating the annotation type with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`. However, this annotation also becomes applicable in declaration contexts due to the bad decision of the Java designers.

According to the Java SE documentation, it reads:

> The constant `TYPE_USE` corresponds to the type contexts in JLS 4.11, as well as to two declaration contexts: type declarations (including annotation type declarations) and type parameter declarations.
>
> For example, an annotation whose type is meta-annotated with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)` may be written on the type of a field (or within the type of the field, if it is a nested, parameterized, or array type), and may also appear as a modifier for, say, a class declaration.
>
> The `TYPE_USE` constant includes type declarations and type parameter declarations as a convenience for designers of type checkers which give semantics to annotation types. For example, if the annotation type NonNull is meta-annotated with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`, then `@NonNull class C {...}` could be treated by a type checker as indicating that all variables of class `C` are non-null, while still allowing variables of other classes to be non-null or not non-null based on whether `@NonNull` appears at the variable's declaration.

Nonetheless, I believe `TYPE_USE` was originally intended to be used in 16 type contexts as described in [JLS 4.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.11). But the Java designers made a decision to extend its usage to declaration contexts.

**I wonder:**

- WHY on earth did they make this decision when you can expand an annotation's applicability simply by adding more elements to the `@Target` annotation. Any specific reason other than "convenience"?
- HOW can I create an annotation type that is ONLY applicable in type contexts? (aka. Pure type annotation)

Comment: Your first question is only answerable by the language designers, and hence, not suitable for Stack Overflow. For your second question, do you realise that type annotations, when applied on a declaration, will apply to all the uses of the declared type?

Comment: @Sweeper I twitted Joshua Bloch for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, @Sweeper gave the reason.  Conventionally a type annotation written on a type declaration is treated as applying to every use of the type.  This is such a common idiom that it would be troublesome to require every annotation designer to expand the `@Target` annotation.  Furthermore, writing `@Target({TYPE_USE, TYPE})` would be *misleading*, because it declares an annotation that is both a type annotation and a declaration annotation, which is not the designer's goal and has a different meaning than the designer's goal.

Here is another advantage to the Java design.  In a field or method declaration, Java distinguishes declaration annotations on the declaration from type annotations on the field type or method return type.  The ability to write a `TYPE_USE` annotation on a class declaration gives a similar way to distinguish the intent and purpose of annotations written on class declarations.

Regarding your second question, you can write an annotation processor that issues an error when an annotation in written at a location that you wish to prohibit.  You are already using an annotation processor to enforce the semantics of type annotations, so you just need to tweak it.

Comment: I tweeted James Gosling, the father of Java, and Joshua Bloch, the author of `ElementType.java` for clarification but none of them have responded yet.

Comment: You would be better off accepting the answer.  Neither James Gosling (who left Oracle in 2010) nor Josh Bloch (who left Sun in 2004) was involved in this aspect of the Java design, which postdated their involvement with the language.