# Is it redundant with `TYPE_USE` to declare other `TYPE` targets?

Tags: java, annotations

Consider this declaration of an annotation type `Foo`:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;

@Target({ ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE, TYPE_PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
public @interface Foo {}
```

Here I think `ANNOTATION_TYPE` is made redundant by `TYPE`, but I wonder what is made redundant by `TYPE_USE`. The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) has this to say:

> The constant `TYPE_USE` corresponds to the type contexts in [JLS 4.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.11), as well as to two declaration contexts: type declarations (including annotation type declarations) and type parameter declarations.
>
> For example, an annotation whose type is meta-annotated with … `TYPE_USE` may be written on the type of a field … and may also appear as a modifier for, say, a class declaration.

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1) says much the same.

Does this mean that target `TYPE_USE` makes each of the other targets of `Foo` redundant? Or what would change if I dropped them from the declaration?

Answer (score 3):

No. On the contrary - they almost (but not quite) are mutually exclusive with TYPE_USE.

TYPE_USE refers to the concept of annotating a, well, usage of a type someplace. Whereas TYPE refers to annotating a type.

Example of putting an annotation on a thing in the sense of TYPE:

```
@MyAnno class ThisDefinesAClass {}
```

Example of putting an annotation on a thing in the sense of TYPE_USE:

```
public void example(List<@ThisIsTypeUse String> names) {}
```

Note how the TYPE_USE annotation is associated with the *USAGE* of a type, not the definition of a type. We aren't defining String. Merely using it.

Where it gets a little nutty is in something like this:

```
public @ThisIsUhWhatIsThis String example() {}
```

This is ambigious: Are you annotating the definition of the `example` method, or, are you annotating the usage of `String`, as part of the return type of the `example` method?

If your annotation is specced to allow TYPE_USE only, then this is considered as annotating the `String` part. If the annotation is specced to allow METHOD, then this is considered to be annotating the entire method.

If it's specced to allow *BOTH*, then it's a weird mishmash of rules that requires reviewing the JLS every time because they are neccessarily weird and confusing. Thus, it is almost always a good idea *NOT* to mix TYPE_USE with anything else.

Sometimes the definitions boil down to the same thing, but usually TYPE_USE is the better way to think about it. Example:

```
public @NonNull String getFoo() {return foo;}
```

This annotation is ambiguous. However, both interpretations lead to the same conclusion:

- This annotation means that the entire method 'getFoo' has been annotated as a 'NonNull' method. Whilst one can conjure up any number of things as to what this might mean, if I tell you that it means: "It will never return null", I'm sure you'd find that a completely plausible thing (and it is, in fact, what @NonNull annotations that predate the existence of TYPE_USE mean, and for presumably backwards compat reasons, a lot of nonnull annotations still work like that: They target methods and params and fields, not TYPE_USE).
- The alternative interpretation says that this annotation means that the use of 'String' as return type is so annotated: This is a method. Its return type is `@NonNull String`, as in, the type `String`, but tagged as `@NonNull`. This means, of course, the same thing: This method cannot return null. But this way of thinking makes more sense. For example, the old way means you simply cannot communicate the notion of 'the first parameter of this method must either be a null pointer, or a pointer to some instance of List, which is constrained to contain only Strings. Those pointers to Strings that the list has must ALL be non-null. That'd be `@Nullable List<@NonNull String>`, and you need TYPE_USE to express concepts like this.

Comment: Your `@MyAnno class ThisDefinesAClass` compiles for me when `MyAnno` targets `TYPE_USE`. If instead I have it target both `TYPE_USE` and `TYPE`, then what changes? How would the addition of `TYPE` not be redundant? (I edit my original question on these lines, to clarify.)

Comment: Try annotating a __`void`__ method with a TYPE_USE only annotation, for example. The difference between TYPE_USE and TYPE is primarily in what it means, not in when you can apply it, but that difference sometimes does result in applicability issues. Such as TYPE_USE and void methods: No can do.

Comment: A TYPE_USE anno put on a class is [A] legal and [B] gets returned if you query for the type annos on the class. In that sense, TYPE and TYPE_USE are indeed more or less superfluous, but that's where it ends. METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER and all the rest are not subsets of type use nor is type-use a subset of them. Furthermore, what an annotation targeted at TYPE_USE means is completely different from what TYPE would mean. Something like `@SuppressWarnings` as TYPE_USE is complete gobbledygook - makes no sense at all.

Comment: Re what `TYPE_USE` means: I found a [post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/type-annotations-spec-experts/2013-November/000174.html) by Alex Buckley implying that `TYPE_USE` is meant to be a proper superset of the other ‘TYPE’ targets, comprising those *plus* type-use targets (type contexts, as the JLS calls them). But type use in itself has no `ElementType` constant and [cannot be targeted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926215) in isolation. `TYPE_USE` does not *mean* type use. Or so I begin to think, and I wrote up an answer to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, given a target of `TYPE_USE`, nothing changes if you add `TYPE`, `ANNOTATION_TYPE` or `TYPE_PARAMETER` to the list of targets.  Targeting `TYPE_USE` makes all other ‘TYPE’ targets redundant.

During the public review of the [JSR](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=308) that introduced the `TYPE_USE` constant, co-lead Alex Buckley [wrote](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/type-annotations-spec-experts/2013-November/000172.html):

> The `Foo` type has a `TYPE_USE` target, so `@Foo` can appear in at least the places permitted by a `TYPE` target, which includes declarations of annotation types.

And [again](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/type-annotations-spec-experts/2013-November/000174.html), in the same thread:

> JSR 308 introduced `ElementType.TYPE_USE` as pertaining not only to uses of types but also to declarations of types; logically, it's a "supertype" of `ElementType.TYPE`.

Recall that `ElementType` [defines](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) its constants each as a class of ‘syntactic locations… where it is legal to write annotations’.  Taking Alex at his word, then, `TYPE_USE` is not specific to locations of use, but a catch-all for locations of declaration *and* use.  Logically a `TYPE` location *is* a `TYPE_USE` location.  The same logic applies to the other ‘TYPE’ constants, which means these two declarations of `Foo` are equivalent:

```
@Target({ TYPE_USE, TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE_PARAMETER })
public @interface Foo {} // is the same as:

@Target({ TYPE_USE })
public @interface Foo {}
```

*It might help to think of `TYPE_USE` as a *superset* of the other ‘TYPE’ locations.  Alex might even have meant to say ‘superset’ instead of ‘supertype’.  Either way, the conclusion would be the same: `TYPE_USE` alone covers all the other ‘TYPE’ locations.*

*It would certainly help if the constants could somehow be renamed.  A catch-all by the name of ‘TYPE’ (instead of ‘TYPE_USE’) together with ‘TYPE_DECLARATION’ (instead of ‘TYPE’), and so forth, would make things much clearer.*

Comment: You're focusing rather a lot on what javac does(n't) allow. The semantic meaning of TYPE_USE and the various TYPE enumvalues are completely different.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, Yes, I think `javac` enforces all the semantics of `Target`, which are limited to an annotation’s applicability, what the [JLS defines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3) as a restriction on “the kinds of program element where [the annotation] may appear”. These elements the [API defines](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) similarly as “syntactic locations where annotations may appear”, and then defines `TYPE_USE` locations as a proper superset of `TYPE` locations.

Comment: Not that kind of 'semantics'. The kind that reflects 'but what does it represent'. It's the difference between explaining the process of how nerves in the stomach contracting cause a hormonal chain to occur, vs saying "I ate the sandwich cuz I'm hungry". TYPE_USE and TYPE mean completely different things. TYPE_USE is not some sort of superset, not by way of _what it means_.