# `TYPE_USE` vs `TYPE` vs `TYPE_PARAMETER` annotations

Tags: java-8, jsr

I am trying to understand what would be correct usage of the annotations mentioned in the title.

I am aware of `TYPE` annotation usage as specified from answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550292/what-do-java-annotation-elementtype-constants-mean) and java docs.

However after reading the [article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Type-Annotations-in-Java-8/) and going through the mail chain [here](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/compiler-dev/2015-December/009874.html) I still have some grey areas as to what would be right usage of `TYPE_USE` annotation.

The grey areas for me are as follows.

1. As mentioned in the previous stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65443843/is-it-redundant-with-type-use-to-declare-other-type-targets) is it a shorter form as mentioned in the 2nd answer.
2. Does it only allow use case like below to have better type safety?

```
 class PersonDto {
 
   private List<@Valid Address> addresses;


  // Some other code...
}
```

3. How is the code referred in 2nd point different from type check perspective to below code.

```
 class PersonDto {
 
  @Valid
  private List<Address> addresses;


  // Some other code...
 }
```

4. As per mail chain mentioned above and my experiment with JDK-17 the example given in mail-chain it seems to be compiling fine. Proving my assumption in point 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Annotation @Target(ElementType.TYPE\_USE) - Also covers declaration contexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910997/java-annotation-targetelementtype-type-use-also-covers-declaration-contexts)